# Wordpress plugin not showing on page

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins

it could be a stupid question, but I just can't find the answer to it. A few minutes ago I installed WPForms to create a contact form for my website. The setup went fine, I have checked it multiple times, but it won't display on my page. 
I am using my own child theme from mh-magazine-lite.

The link to the website: http://st359450.cmd16c.cmi.hanze.nl/drimble/contact/ (Please note it's the first wp website my group has ever made for a school project, so it's not great)

Why can't I see the form on my page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Navigate to the back-end of your WordPress website. (That's usually yoururl/wp-admin.)
2. In the menu that's on the left-hand side of the page, you should see a tab that says WPForms. Hover over that tab, then click add new.
3. When you finish customizing the form, copy the embed code (top right | next to save button), it should look something like this:**[wpforms id="1712"]**
4. Once you copy the code, go to the desired page you want to post the form on,
   and click edit page.
5. Once you're in the editor, make sure the Text tab is selected, not the Visual tab. Paste the embed code in there. It should work then

   Hope this helps.

Comment: I think you misunderstood my question.. I have made the form, but when I add it to my page, I can't see it

Comment: Looks like it has a form on your url:)

Answer (score 0):

The form is already added to your webpage. The reason you can not see it is that the code has been commented. So in the plugin settings check whether there's an option to *activate* or *visible* the form. Or if you can edit the html code in the relevant page remove `<!--` before and `-->` after the form.

[image: Form]